# What happens if connect 2 points with different potential?

Tags: electric-circuits, voltage, short-circuits

I have a very basic question on charge distribution in electric circuits. Let's say we have 2 independent circuits. If we connect a point with higher potential in one circuit to a point with a lower potential from another circuit, would voltage between those 2 points get redistributed? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what `equalize surface charges` means, but **yes**, charge gets redistributed and shared in this new part of the circuit as there will be a new equilibrium potential in between the two original values in the seperated systems.

Remember though that their potential must be measured with the same reference (or else you could not know if one was higher than the other.)